# Linkedin share plugin not submitting form

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn share button on my site with the following html:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>

<script type="IN/Share" data-url="www.aidh.co.uk/blog/1506-exposure/default.html"></script>
```

The button brings up the Linkedin plug in with all of the content correct and options for sharing.

https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=www.aidh.co.uk%2Fblog%2F1506-exposure%2Fdefault.html&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aidh.co.uk%2Fblog%2F1506-exposure%2Fdefault.html&token=&isFramed=false&lang=en_US&_ts=1432834994124.3257

However the share button on Linkedin's own page doesn't submit the information to Linkedin.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of LinkedIn plugin.

(https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.  It seems like the only valid format is something in the following form...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

For example...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Frevoltlib.com%2F
```

This means that you *only* have the `url` param to modify.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained github project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]